# how do I sort elements within an array by first alphabet then second alphabet etc?

Tags: python, arrays, string, sorting

How do I sort the following items within the list names = ["Pat","Lily","Dom] by the first alphabet, and if the first alphabet is the same then by second alphabet and so on...

I tried using x = list(map(sorted, names) but this splits up the strings into individual letters and only sorts the last element Dom, which is absolutely not what I am after.

Any help? Is map() the right things to use in this case? Thanks

Comment: `sorted(names)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names = ["Pat","Lily","Dom"]
sorted(names)
```